# Запросить разрешение в CanvasWatchFaceService

Tags: java, android, android-wear

Есть сервис CanvasWatchFaceService в нём CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine и больше ничего. Никаких активити. Падает на часах потому что нету разрешений(permissions). Что-то я не нашёл как выдать разрешение в сервисе на часах. Подскажите, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: а в манифесте пермишены указаны?

Comment: конечно, интересует именно экранные разрешения https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html

Comment: вам разрешение на показ элементов поверх других элементов?

Comment: получение местоположения ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION